# Input two sorted lists or arrays and sort them in python 3

Tags: python, mergesort

For example
take input 2 lists
Like `1,7,9,21`
And `2,5,8`

I want `1,2,5,7,8,9,21` as output

**Please note:**
The length of the lists are not constant and the two lists can have different number of elements

Answer (score 0):

Assuming inputs can be assigned to lists:

```
lst1 = [1, 7, 9, 21]
lst2 = [2, 5, 8]

sorted(lst1 + lst2)  # [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 21]
```

Comment: And how to take input those two lists?

Comment: That's a separate question. I have no idea how user is inputting variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate lists and then use *sort* method to sort the list.
As:

```
a = [1, 7, 9, 21]
b = [2, 5, 8]
c = a + b
print (c.sort())
```